# Avoiding unwanted return value in a java lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Is there any way to avoid the `return null` in this code?

```
@Test
public void testFrontEndPing() throws Exception {
    String url = frontEndUrl("ping");
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    httpClient.execute(httpGet, httpResponse -> {
            assertEquals(200, httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            return null;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: the best kind of solution that I know - http://bayou.io/release/0.9/javadoc/bayou/util/function/Callable_Void.html

Comment: for you case, a helper method that takes func `(Response->void)` would work.

Comment: John Rose - http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-September/011020.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a wrapper method like this:

```
static void execute(HttpClient client, HttpUriRequest request,
                    Consumer<HttpResponse> handler) {
    client.<Void>execute(request, response -> {
        handler.accept(response);
        return null;
    });
}
```

And use it like this:

```
execute(httpClient, httpGet, httpResponse -> 
    assertEquals(200, httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()));
```

Comment: `<Void>` should be unnecessary. `null` fits every type, regardless of what the compiler infers.

Answer (score 2):

The Functional Interface you're trying to work with mandates that the function return an object. So no matter how you code this functionality, somewhere you'll have to include 'return null;'

I would advise that you analyze what the code is meant to do, and whether, per the design of your code, you really want that method to always return null.

Comment: well, `Void` *should* be treated the same as `void` in a lot of cases. It was on java8 designer's mind - http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-November/006685.html

Comment: @bayou.io: even if `Void` is treated the same as `void`, you would required the compiler to infer `Void` as a return type rather than `Object` in this case unless you want to have to use `httpClient.<Void>execute(httpGet, httpResponse -> …)`. So there’s more to it…

Comment: @Holger - without a return statement, the lambda body returns void, which can be "boxed" as Void. Analogy - if lambda body returns `int`, and the function requires a reference type, boxing occurs, and the lambda return type is Integer

Comment: @bayou.io: that’s reasonable from a programmers point of view, but unfortunately, the compiler will use target typing here, as the lambda expression is not explicitly typed (the function parameter has no explicit type as opposed to `(HttpResponse httpResponse) -> …`. So that’s all a bit more complicated. Nevertheless, the compiler developers should do that complicated work so all others don’t have to, that’s out of question.

Comment: @Holger - yes it's complicated, but it seems doable, according to those java guys.

Comment: @bayou.io, actually this can break the compatibility in many cases including using some JDK APIs. E.g. there's `ExecutorService.submit(Callable<T>)` and `ExecutorService.submit(Runnable)`. I guess there is already plenty of code using `service.submit(() -> runSomethingVoid());` which matches to `Runnable` now. Such code will become ambiguous with your proposed change: it would be legal to match it to both `Callable<Void>` and `Runnable`.

Comment: @TagirValeev - It would match `()->void` better, because no boxing/unboxing step is needed. Currently we can see that behavior with `int/Integer`. Try overload `foo( ()->int )` and `foo( ()->Integer )`, we'll see that the more fitting method is picked based on lambda return type.